# Sending message over websocket

Tags: go, websocket

The task is simple: make a connection and send a message to the user

After reading on the Internet, it turns out something like this

Connection

```
func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    con, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer con.Close()
    for {
        mt, message, err := con.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        err = con.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
}
```

Sending a message from a method

```
jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(data)
users := make(map[string]*websocket.Conn)
_ = users[uid].WriteJSON(jsonData)
```

As you can imagine, it doesn't work and I'm in some kind of stupor.
Can you please tell me, am I actually acting in the right direction?
I am sure that someone has already done this very simple setting, please respond =)

Comment: The general approach of using a map keyed by uid is good.  There are a few issues with the code in the question: (1) The application double-encodes `data` as JSON.   Encode it once using `_ = users[uid].WriteJSON(data)`.   (2) The expression `users[uid]` evaluates to a nil pointer because the map is created on the previous line. Create the map once. Protected it with a mutex. (3) Always check errors. The return value from WriteJSON is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code below, ask questions if you get lost.

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

var router = mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  0,
    WriteBufferSize: 0,
}

type tester struct {
    Results int    `json:"Results"`
    ID      int    `json:"ID"`
    User    string `json:"User"`
}

var testers tester
var list = ""

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Home Page")
} 
func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        //read in a message
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        //printing out the message in the server for clarity
        fmt.Println(string(p))
        list = string(p)
        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
}
func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //This will determine whether or not an incoming request from
    // a different domain is allowed to connect, and if it isn’t they’ll be hit with a CORS error.
    upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }

    //upgrade this connection to a webSocket connection
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        // helpful log statement to show connections
        log.Println("Client Connected")

        for {
            //read in a message
            _, p, err := ws.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            //printing out the message in the server for clarity
            list = string(p)
            fmt.Println(list)
        }
    }

}

// define a reader which will listen for
// new messages being sent to our WebSocket
// endpoint

func setupRoutes() {
    router.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    router.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
}
func main() {
    setupRoutes()
    handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(router)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler))
}
```